# How can I set in the midst?

Tags: java, draw, center

I try to draw a rectangular in Java.  I set the frame size (800,400) and resizable(false) rectangular's x = 50, y = 50 width = 700 height = 300. Why isn't it in the middle? Thank you.

Comment: where is it located on the screen?

Comment: I'm putting my money on this being that the left and top margins of the window are messing with your coordinates. Can you post a screenshot? EDIT: Also, is this swing? If so you should retag it for optimal findable-ness

Comment: I'm betting you're overriding `paint` on the frame directly, which means that you're not taking into consideration the frame's decortations

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Without any evidence otherwise, I'd *guess* you've overriden the `paint` method of something like a `JFrame` and are painting directly to it.

The problem is, frames have decoration (a border and title bar for example), which takes up space **inside** the frame...

[image]

Technically, this is correct.  The rectangle is painted in the center of frame, but the because of the frame's decorations, it looks like it's slightly high...

Instead, you should be painting onto the frame's content area instead.

[image]

Here the rectangle now looks correctly centered.  In my tests, I set the first frame (bad) to 800x400, I made the second frame's content pane's preferred size 800x400, which made the frame size actually 816x438, as the frame's decorations are now *outside* of the paint area.

```
public class CenterOfFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new CenterOfFrame();
    }

    public CenterOfFrame() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                new BadFrame().setVisible(true);

                JFrame goodFrame = new JFrame();
                goodFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                goodFrame.setContentPane(new PaintablePane());
                goodFrame.pack();
                goodFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                goodFrame.setVisible(true);

            }
        });
    }

    public class BadFrame extends JFrame {

        public BadFrame() {
            setSize(800, 400);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        }

        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            super.paint(g);
            paintTest(g, getWidth() - 1, getHeight() - 1);
        }
    }

    public void paintTest(Graphics g, int width, int height) {
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.drawLine(0, 0, width, height);
        g.drawLine(width, 0, 0, height);
        g.drawRect(50, 50, width - 100, height - 100);
    }

    public class PaintablePane extends JPanel {

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(800, 400);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
            paintTest(g, getWidth() - 1, getHeight() - 1);
        }
    }
}
```

This is, one of many reasons, why you should not override the `paint` method of top level containers ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(50,50,700,300);
```

That should work fine, are you creating a new instance of Rectangle before you access member variables?

Also 800 by 400 it kind of a weird resolution, 800 by 600 is more standard.