# paint method draws outside jFrame if first coord 0,0

Tags: java, swing, jframe, paintcomponent

First coord in this case should be 0,0 and not 8,30. What am i doing wrong(i am using NetBeans)

[image]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
public class TEST extends javax.swing.JFrame {

@Override
public void paint(Graphics g){
    super.paint(g);
    g.setColor(Color.blue);
    g.drawRect(8, 30, 200, 200);
    repaint();
}}
```

Comment: `g` is a graphic context of the frame. Now the title bar is a part of the frame too. As a result (0,0) means the top left of the frame, not the top left of the drawing area as you are expecting.

Comment: Frame's have decorations which take up space WITHIN the confines of the frame.  Painting directly onto a frame is not recommended as 1. You run into this issue and 2. Frame's contain other components (content pane, menus, layer and glass panes).  Check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13734069/how-can-i-set-in-the-midst/13734319#13734319) for more information.  You should use a custom component (like `JPanel`) and either add it to the content pane or replace the frame's content pane with it.

Answer (score 4):

Add a `JPanel` to the frame and paint in that. The frame's coordinates include the decorations (title bar, borders, etc.). It would look something like this:

```
public class Test extends JFrame {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }
    private Test() {
        add(new MyPanel());
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(600, 600);
        setVisible(true);
    }
    private class MyPanel extends JPanel {
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.setColor(Color.blue);
            g.drawRect(8, 30, 200, 200);
        }
    }
}
```

Also, don't call `repaint();` in `paint();`. That will cause an infinite loop and will freeze the entire program.

Comment: *"`..Test extends JFrame..`"*  Why extend frame?  Just use an instance of one.

Comment: +1 AndrewThompson, @DoorKnob Also always create Swing components on Event Dispatch Thread and dont call setSize rather call `pack()` on `JFrame` (and override `getPreferredSize()` of `JPanel` - see my answer for more). +1 for `paintComponent` `JPanel` and `repaint()` advice.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I was just trying to keep it as similar to the original program as possible. I usually wouldn't do this.

Comment: @Doorknob Dont give OP code which demonstrates bad practices as he/or she might think this is the correct way of doing it and thus learns *incorrect* methods, rather correct their mistakes for the future IMO.

Comment: Thanks helped me out a lot tho i had some trouble in the beggining but fuigerd it out(i implemented this in another program)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is your `paint(..)` method is not taking into account the `JFrame` `Insets` by calling `getInsets` which as [docs state](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#getInsets%28%29):

> If a border has been set on this component, returns the border's
>   insets.

this code works fine:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Test {

    public Test() {
        createAndShowGui();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Test();
            }
        });
    }

    private void createAndShowGui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame() {
            @Override
            public void paint(Graphics g) {
                super.paint(g);
                g.setColor(Color.blue);
                g.drawRect(0 + getInsets().left, 0 + getInsets().top, 200, 200);
            }
        };
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

however this is not best practice.

Rather add `JPanel` to `JFrame` and override `paintComponent(Graphics g)` of `JPanel` dont forget call to `super.paintComponent(g)` as first call in the overridden method and than draw there (dont forget to override `getPreferredSize()` and return correct `Dimension`s so the `JPanel` will fit its drawing/graphic content) this problem will no longer persist as `JPanel` is added at correct co-ordinates on *contentPane* like so:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Test {

    public Test() {
        createAndShowGui();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Test();
            }
        });
    }

    private void createAndShowGui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel() {
            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                super.paintComponent(g);
                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
                g2d.addRenderingHints(new RenderingHints(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY));
                g2d.setColor(Color.blue);
                g2d.drawRect(0, 0, 200, 200);
            }

            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(300, 300);
            }
        };

        frame.add(panel);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

The above includes `Graphics2D` and RenderingHints i.e anti-aliasing. Just for some better looking drawings :)