# why JPanel never calls a reapint

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

Hi I wanted to write a simple arcanoid game but for some reason my JPanel.repaint() is never called and my ball doesn't move. So in my main class extends JPanel to the JPanel I add a listener that is called when user wants to start a game and as a result a thread is fired this thread changes the position of the ball and should (ideally) call the repaint on my jpanel class. I checked the position of the ball changes but the repaint method is never called. Can someone please help? Thanks in advance here is my code:

```
public class test extends JPanel{
int x=250;
int y=470;
int width=100;
int height=20;
Ball b=new Ball();
public static void main(String[] args){
    test t=new test();
    t.draw();
}
public void draw(){
    JFrame frame=new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(520, 520);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    this.setSize(500,500);
    frame.add(this);
    this.addMouseListener(new mouseL());
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    System.out.println("Yeah I am called");

    Graphics2D g2d=(Graphics2D) g;
    g2d.setColor(Color.blue);
    g2d.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
    g2d.setColor(b.getColor());
    g2d.fillOval(b.x1, b.y1, b.width1, b.height1);
}
class Ball{
    Random rand=new Random();
    int x1=300;
    int y1=450;
    int height1=20;
    int width1=20;
    Color c;
    public Color getColor(){
        return new Color(rand.nextInt(255), rand.nextInt(255), rand.nextInt(255));
    }
}
class mouseL implements MouseListener{
    Thread t=new Thread(new MyRun());

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        t.run();


    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
class MyRun implements Runnable{

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try{
        while(true){
            //System.out.println("Yeah I work");
            test.this.b.x1=test.this.b.x1-1;
            test.this.b.y1=test.this.b.y1-1;
            System.out.println("the values are: "+test.this.b.x1+" and "+test.this.b.y1);
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            test.this.repaint();
        }
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`t.run();` calls (in your case) `Runnabe#run`, which is executed from within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread, thereby freezing your UI for ever.

You should have used `t.start()`

Because Swing is single threaded, you are running the risk of race conditions and dirty read/writes between the variables.  A safer and simpler solution would be to use a Swing `Timer`, see [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html), which schedules it's notifications within the EDT, making safe to update the UI from

Also, take a look at [How can I set in the midst?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13734069/how-can-i-set-in-the-midst/13734319#13734319) for reasons why you shouldn't use `JFrame#setSize` and should instead, override the `getPreferredSize` method of your `JPanel` and call `JFrame#pack` instead