# Can't draw more than one square in JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, paint

Can't get the program to print more than one square.

---

My code right now

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MyApplication extends JFrame {

    private static final Dimension WindowSize = new Dimension(600, 600);
    private int xCord=9, yCord=32, width=80, height=80;

    public MyApplication() {
        //Create and set up the window
        this.setTitle("Squares");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //Display the window centered on the screen
        Dimension screensize = java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        int x = screensize.width / 2 - WindowSize.width / 2;
        int y = screensize.height / 2 - WindowSize.height / 2;
        setBounds(x, y, WindowSize.width, WindowSize.height);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        MyApplication window = new MyApplication();
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        int red = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
        int green = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
        int blue = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
        g.setColor(Color.getHSBColor(red, green, blue));
        g.fillRect(xCord, yCord, width, height);

        while((yCord+height)<600){
            if((xCord+width)>600){
                xCord=9;
                yCord+=80;
            }
            else xCord+=80;
            repaint();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to fill a 600x600 window with squares of different colours that go to a new line once a row is full.

Comment: Can you tell us what you think paint() and repaint() do?

Comment: Try putting g.fillRect(xCord, yCord, width, height); in your while loop, you are changing the coordinates but you're not drawing with graphics

Comment: Well, I asked my professor and he said that paint() is invoked by the OS whenever stuff in the window needs painting.
repaint() just enforces it
At least That's my understanding of it.

Comment: @JRowan that fixed it thanks.

Comment: *"repaint() just enforces it "* - That's both correct and incorrect. `repaint` is a "request" to the painting system.  The painting system will then decide what and when something get's painted, so making multiple `repaint` requests could see them optimised down to a single paint pass.  Also, painting is destructive, this means you are expected to repaint the entire state of a component on each paint pass

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, don't.

Don't override `paint` of top level containers, like `JFrame`.

`JFrame` is a composite component, meaning that they're a number of layers between its surface and the user and because of the way the paint system works, these can be painted independent of the frame, which can produce weird results.

[image: A frames layers]

Top level containers are not double buffered, meaning your updates will flash.

DO call a paint methods super method, unless you are absolutely sure you know what you're doing.

Start by taking a look at [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) and [Painting in AWT and Swing](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) for more details about how painting works in Swing and how you should work with it.

This...

```
Dimension screensize = java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
int x = screensize.width / 2 - WindowSize.width / 2;
int y = screensize.height / 2 - WindowSize.height / 2;
setBounds(x, y, WindowSize.width, WindowSize.height);
```

is a bad idea on a number of levels.

`Toolkit#getScreenSize` does not take into consideration the size of other UI elements which will reduce the available viewable area available on the screen, things like the taskbar/dock or menu bar on some OS

Using `setBounds(x, y, WindowSize.width, WindowSize.height);` on a window based class is also a bad idea, as the avaliable viewable area is the window size MINUS the window's decorations, meaning the actually viewable area is smaller then you have specified and because you're painting directly to the frame, you run the risk of painting under the frame decorations.

You can have a look at [How can I set in the midst?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13734069/how-can-i-set-in-the-midst/13734319#13734319) for more details

One thing you should now about painting, painting is destructive, that is, each time a paint cycle occurs, you are expected to completely repaint the current state of the component.

Currently, this...

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    int red = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
    int green = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
    int blue = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
    g.setColor(Color.getHSBColor(red, green, blue));
    g.fillRect(xCord, yCord, width, height);

    while ((yCord + height) < 600) {
        if ((xCord + width) > 600) {
            xCord = 9;
            yCord += 80;
        } else {
            xCord += 80;
        }
        repaint();
    }
}
```

will only paint a single rectangle, base on the last value of `xCord` and `yCord` most likely AFTER the `paint` method has exited.

Swing uses a passive rendering engine, meaning that the system will make determinations about what to paint and when, you don't control it.  You can make a "request" to the system through the use `repaint`, but it's up to the system to decide when and what will get painted, this means that multiple requests can be optimised down to a single paint pass.

Also, painting should do nothing more than paint the current state. It should avoid changing the state, directly or indirectly, especially if that change triggers a new paint pass, as this can suddenly reduce the performance of your program to 0, crippling it.

## So, what's the answer?

Well, change everything...

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class MyApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MyApplication();
    }

    public MyApplication() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public static class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private static final Dimension DESIRED_SIZE = new Dimension(600, 600);
        private int width = 80, height = 80;

        public TestPane() {
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return DESIRED_SIZE;
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();

            int xCord = 0, yCord = 0;

            while ((yCord) < getHeight()) {
                int red = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
                int green = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
                int blue = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
                g2d.setColor(Color.getHSBColor(red, green, blue));
                g2d.fillRect(xCord, yCord, width, height);
                if ((xCord + width) > getWidth()) {
                    xCord = 0;
                    yCord += 80;
                } else {
                    xCord += 80;
                }
            }
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }

}
```

[image: Lots of squares]

## Break down...

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.add(new TestPane());
frame.pack();
frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

This creates an instance of `Jframe`, you don't really want extend from `JFrame`, you're not adding any new functionality to the class

`frame.pack()` is packing the window around the content, this ensures that the frame is always larger (by the amount of the frame decorations) then the desired content size

`frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);` will centre the window in a system independent manner.

Next...

```
private static final Dimension DESIRED_SIZE = new Dimension(600, 600);
private int width = 80, height = 80;

public TestPane() {
}

@Override
public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    return DESIRED_SIZE;
}
```

I've used `DESIRED_SIZE` to provide a sizing hint to the parent containers layout manager.

Finally...

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
    
    int xCord = 0, yCord = 0;
    while ((yCord) < getHeight()) {
        int red = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
        int green = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
        int blue = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
        g2d.setColor(Color.getHSBColor(red, green, blue));
        g2d.fillRect(xCord, yCord, width, height);
        if ((xCord + width) > getWidth()) {
            xCord = 0;
            yCord += 80;
        } else {
            xCord += 80;
        }
    }
    g2d.dispose();
}
```

Note here, I've changed the `xCord` and `yCord` positions to zero, I no longer need to "guess" at the frame decorations.  As well as making the local variables, so that when ever the method is called again, the values are reset to zero.

You don't "have" to cast the `Graphics` reference to `Graphics2D`, but `Graphics2D` is a more powerful API.  I also like to copy it's state, but that's me, your code is simple enough so it's unlikely to have adverse effects on anything else that might be painted after your component.

Notice also, I've use `getWidth` and `getHeight` instead of "magic numbers", meaning you can resize the window and the painting will adapt.

Comment: `Color.getHSBColor(red, green, blue)` (appears twice) should probably be `new Color(red, green, blue)`. And shouldn't `xCord` and `yCord` be local variables, otherwise the pane cannot repaint itself when it is resized or parts of it were obscured, though that would not really matter since a different random color will be chosen. Therefore maybe it would be good to use a `Random` with `yCord` as seed.

Comment: @Marcono1234 Yes the cords should be reset - but I could also pre-cache the Rectangle’s, but small steps

Comment: @Marcono1234 Done update. Personally not to concerned about `Color`, but yes, I'd use RGB

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thanks a lot for the answered it helped A LOT. One question if you don't mind. What's the point of having `protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)`? Why not have `Graphics2D g2d`?
Also why call `super.paintComponent(g);` ? What does it do ?

Comment: @ertagon2 Why does it need to be `protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)`?  Because that's the [method signature](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paintComponent(java.awt.Graphics)) - try changing it see what happens. The (newly added `@Override`) will stop it from compiling, because there is no such method in the parent classes.

Comment: @ertagon2 History lesson, somewhere around Java 1.3, the core team changed the `Graphics` implementation to better support the new graphics pipeline, adding in `Graphics2D` - this means that the instance of `Graphics` passed to your paint methods by the system is guaranteed to be an instance of `Graphics2D`.

Comment: @ertagon2 *"Also why call super.paintComponent(g); ? What does it do ? "* - This is a little more abstract, you should always call a methods super when overriding, unless you 100% sure you understand what you are doing and are prepared to take responsibility for operations the super method was doing.  In the case of `paintComponent`, this clears `Graphics` context and makes it ready to be painted to (usually by filling it with the components background color). `Graphics` is a shared context, meaning that what ever was paint before your component, used the same `Graphics` context

Answer (score 0):

You could try placing the whole paint mechanism inside your loop to get it done with in a one call. Therefore you wont need to call repaint inside the paint method itself:

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {

    while((yCord+height)<600){

        int red = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
        int green = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
        int blue = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
        g.setColor(Color.getHSBColor(red, green, blue));
        g.fillRect(xCord, yCord, width, height);

        if((xCord+width)>600){
            xCord=9;
            yCord+=80;
        }
        else xCord+=80;
    }
}
```